# How can I remove all child elements of body element with DOMDocument?

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to remove all `body` children with DOMDocument.

```
$dom = new DomDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($buffer);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE; 

$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

$bodyChilden = $body->childNodes; // NULL, so invalid argument for foreach

foreach($bodyChildren as $child) {
    $child->parentNode->removeChild($child);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong... please tell me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the problem is that you're updating the `$bodyChildren` iterator (it's not an array, it's a `DomNodeList` object) as you're looping over it.  Instead, try doing this:

```
while ($bodyChildren->length > 0) {
    $body->removeChild($bodyChildren->item(0));
}
```

It seems a bit backwards, but it should work for your needs...